# How secure is Meteor currently?

Tags: meteor

I have read a lot of posts about Meteor's limitations when it comes to data security. More specifically from what I have read, meteor gives full database read/write access on the client side for example using the JS console on Chrome. I was wondering if meteor has released any updates and if now we could deny read/write database access to the clients. I read something about this on the Meteor documentation but am not sure to what extent access could be denied.

Comment: Read the documentation....it says *exactly* how permissions work. Or, you could just watch one of their videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are developing an app, it is useful to have full crud permission on the client. That is what the autopublish and insecure packages are for. In production, you remove those packages and give the client permission only to what you want.

> By default, a new Meteor app includes the autopublish and insecure
>   packages, which together mimic the effect of each client having full
>   read/write access to the server's database. These are useful
>   prototyping tools, but typically not appropriate for production
>   applications. When you're ready, just remove the packages.

http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity

Comment: I'm kinda in doubt of that sentence from the docs. How can it be useful to develop an app using presumptions that won't hold in production and which will probably imply major code structure changes to fix later on? As far as I can tell the only thing autopublish and insecure packages are good for is rapid prototyping and mocking and when you're coding an app intended for production you should remove them immediately. Am I missing something?

Comment: @bbozo even when I just create my site, I remove these packages from the beginning. I can't see the use for those to be honest..